Peer to peer communication using ROUTER-DEALER
I want to establish a communication between two peers (lets say A and B). Where A most of the time sends a message to B and B may or may not reply depending on the message and vice versa. I can think of two set of PUSH PULL socket on both peers, but is the same applicable for ROUTER DEALER but with only one socket? I mean whether it is possible to open a ROUTER socket in A and DEALER socket in B and achieve the above mentioned communication scenario.
I have tried with ROUTER DEALER using cppzmq and able to send message from one peer to another peer in one way communication (i.e. no reply).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How I can go about implementing Peer to Peer communication between two node using ZMQ when the messages exchanged between Peers may not have associated reply? Is this possible to implement using only one ZMQ socket per Peer or do I need multiple socket per Peer, each for one way communication?
